# CMS in functional programming language

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, content-management-system, lisp, clojure

Are there any CMS'es, written in functonal programming languages (lisp, haskell, f#/nemerle, scala, erlang, clojure, smalltalk) already?

Comment: I know, twitter is running on Scala.

Comment: @fortran well, it has some taste of functional language: closures, anonymous functions, higher order functions. actually, it is no less functional than scala in some sense, imho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In OCaml:

- [COCANWIKI](http://sandbox.merjis.com/)
- [ocsimore](http://ocsigen.org/ocsimore/)

Answer (score 10):

The wonderful gitit wiki is written in Haskell: http://gitit.net It uses darcs or git as a storage layer. The darcs wiki runs on gitit, http://wiki.darcs.net/

Answer (score 10):

[Zotonic](http://zotonic.com/) looks promising (in Erlang)

Answer (score 6):

[Lambdium Light](http://www.dse.nl/~dario/projects/lambdium-light/) is a CMS written in OCaml with [Eliom](http://ocsigen.org/eliom/manual/1.2.0/) (Eliom is an extension for the Web server [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) that allows dynamic webpages generation.Ocsigen is also written in [OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/))

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately my answer will be very partial. I hope other people will know more about this topic.

Some subaspects of content management have surely been implemented in Haskell:

- I heard about a wiki system implemented in Haskell: [Flippi](http://www.flippac.org/projects/flippi/). As far as I know, it stayed very minimal, and its maintenance has been discontinued. Haskell wiki is **not** maintained with it.
- As for version control, the Haskell-implemented, quantum-mechanics-inspired [darcs](http://darcs.net/) proved to be successful, and its maintenance is still alive and active.

Some more information about wikis and content management systems implemented in Haskell can be found [here on Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Web_programming#Wikis). There are several attempts for wikis. Two links provided for data management systems (Halipeto and Hope) are broken, but they can be retrieved by [archive.org](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~bringert/darcs/hope/)'s "way-back machine". Still, [Hope's darcs repo is available directly](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~bringert/darcs/hope/), you can check it out by:

**`darcs get --partial http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~bringert/darcs/hope/`**

Comment: I'd strongly recommend looking at what's on Hackage instead. E.g. gitit and orchid, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/orchid There's many other up-to-date web libraries there as well.

Answer (score 3):

For guys, who know russian, there is a common lisp cms [here](http://lisper.ru/) ([github link](http://github.com/archimag/rulisp)).

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, just noticed [pier](http://www.piercms.com/) is missing as a smalltalk cms.

Answer (score 2):

Erlang attempt is [Wikie](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ErlangWiki).

Answer (score 2):

Smalltalk has wonderful [seaside](http://seaside.st) web-framework, with [Dabble DB](http://dabbledb.com) being one of the most famous [users](http://www.seaside.st/about/users) among many other.

Answer (score 1):

There's [reverie](http://reveriecms.org/) or [Vix](https://github.com/fmw/vix) for **Clojure**.

Answer (score 0):

**Haskell**:  [clckwrks](http://www.clckwrks.com/), has plugin and theme support .

**Scala**:

- [Scalapress](https://github.com/sksamuel/scalapress), in active development
- Fink, bulitwith scalartra

Answer (score 0):

[Hoisted](https://github.com/hoisted/hoisted) is a Liftweb based CMS.